# Can't add annotation using core data model class in MapKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit

I tried to use the core data model class as my custom annotation, but somehow the viewForAnnotation never gets called.

Here is my view controller, which contains all the core data snippet and how I implement the delegate method

```
#import "SkyCastViewController.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "Pixel-Swift.h"
#import "Photo+Annotation.h"


static NSString* const NavigationBarTitleFontName = @"Avenir-Heavy";
static CGFloat const NavigationBarTitleFontSize = 17;
static NSString* const MapViewReuseIdentifier = @"AnnotationViweIden";

@interface SkyCastViewController () <MKMapViewDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray* photos;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIManagedDocument* document;



@end

@implementation SkyCastViewController

- (void) viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self updateUI];
    self.mapView.delegate = self;
}

- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    NSFileManager* fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSURL* docsDir = [fileManager URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask].firstObject;
    if(docsDir){
        NSURL* url = [docsDir URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"storage"];
        self.document = [[UIManagedDocument alloc] initWithFileURL: url];
        if(self.document.documentState != UIDocumentStateNormal){
            if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath: url.path]){
                //the document exists, open it
                [self.document openWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success){
                    if(success){
                        [self documentInit];
                    }
                }];
            }else{
                //the document does not exist, create one
                [self.document saveToURL:url forSaveOperation: UIDocumentSaveForCreating completionHandler:^(BOOL success){
                    //post a notification that document is ready
                    if(success){
                        NSLog(@"saveToURL succeed");
                    }else{
                        NSLog(@"saveToURL falied");
                    }
                }];
            }
        }
    }

}




// document ready observer
- (void) documentInit{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSManagedObjectContext* context = self.document.managedObjectContext;
        NSError* error;
        //fetch objects
        NSFetchRequest* request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"User"];
        request.fetchBatchSize = 10;
        request.fetchLimit = 100;
        NSString* nameAttr = @"name";
        NSString* nameValue = @"Kesong Xie";
        request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K like %@", nameAttr, nameValue];
        NSArray* users = [context executeFetchRequest:request error: &error];
        if(error != nil){
            NSLog(@"%@", error.localizedDescription);
        }else{
            if([users count] > 0){
                for(User* user in users){
                    self.photos = (NSArray<Photo<MKAnnotation>*>*)user.photo.allObjects;
                    [self.mapView addAnnotations:self.photos];
                }
            }
        }
        NSLog(@"%@", self.photos);
        //        [self.mapView showAnnotations: self.photos animated: YES];
    });

}


//MARK: - UPATE UI
- (void) updateUI{
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarTintColor: [UIColor blackColor]];
    UIFont* titleFont = [UIFont fontWithName: NavigationBarTitleFontName size: NavigationBarTitleFontSize];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: titleFont,    NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor]}];
}

- (UIStatusBarStyle) preferredStatusBarStyle{
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}


//MARK: - MKMapViewDelegate
-(MKAnnotationView*) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation{
    NSLog(@"called from viewForAnnotation");
    if([annotation isKindOfClass:[ MKUserLocation class]]){
        return nil;
    }
    MKAnnotationView* annotationView = [mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier: MapViewReuseIdentifier];
    if(!annotationView){
        annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:MapViewReuseIdentifier];
    }else{
        annotationView.annotation = annotation;
    }
    UIImage* shot = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"shot3"];
    annotationView.image = shot;
    annotationView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 60);
    annotationView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    return annotationView;
}

@end
```

now the only output on the console is

```
Pixel[1832:440548] (
    "<Pixel.Photo: 0xa03a400> (entity: Photo; id: 0x17e905f0 <x-coredata://FB9198FE-57D1-4C88-945B-0B04D49821C0/Photo/p42> ; data: {\n    latitude = \"32.88831721994364\";\n    longitude = \"-117.2413945199151\";\n    thumbnailData = nil;\n    time = nil;\n    title = \"Beach Walking\";\n    whoTook = \"0xa040660 <x-coredata://FB9198FE-57D1-4C88-945B-0B04D49821C0/User/p10>\";\n})",
    "<Pixel.Photo: 0xa039440> (entity: Photo; id: 0xa038b40 <x-coredata://FB9198FE-57D1-4C88-945B-0B04D49821C0/Photo/p43> ; data: {\n    latitude = \"32.88831721994364\";\n    longitude = \"-117.2413945199151\";\n    thumbnailData = nil;\n    time = nil;\n    title = \"Aerial Shots of Sedona Arizona\";\n    whoTook = \"0xa040660 <x-coredata://FB9198FE-57D1-4C88-945B-0B04D49821C0/User/p10>\";\n})"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please share your viewController code because as per your code shared I can assume that your MapView is initiating after this code.

```
if(error != nil){
            NSLog(@"%@", error.localizedDescription);
        }else{
            if([users count] > 0){
                for(User* user in users){
                    self.photos = (NSArray<Photo<MKAnnotation>*>*)user.photo.allObjects;
                    [self.mapView addAnnotations:self.photos];
                }
            }
        }
        NSLog(@"%@", self.photos);
```

Because in your console these line print right after your MapView is loaded

```
2016-12-09 16:19:42.101997 Pixel[1646:397556] viewForAnnotation called
2016-12-09 16:19:42.102120 Pixel[1646:397556] annotation is the MKUserLocation
```

These line should print before your **CoreData** results

Comment: if it prints before core data, but I haven't had all the annotation set up at that point? how can the map view know how to render the annotation associated with my core data entries?

Comment: I have attached my view controller and also I move all the core data inside this controller so you can see it more clearly. Now the updated code just try to set up some pins using the core data `Photo: NSManagedObject` which conforms to MKAnnotation.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand why I can't load my pin now. The line

```
 self.photos = (NSArray<Photo<MKAnnotation>*>*)user.photo.allObjects;
```

attempted to assign all the `photo(MKAnnotation)`to the `photos`property, but due to the faulting of the core data, the actual "data" is not available until you access it.

Solution: 
create a new `MKAnnotation` class called `PhotoAnnotation`
Here is the code for this class
**PhotoAnnotation.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface PhotoAnnotation : NSObject

@property (nonatomic) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* thumbnailUrl;

- (id) initWithThumbnailUrl:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate url: (NSString*) thumbnailUrl;

@end
```

**##PhotoAnnotation.m**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import "PhotoAnnotation.h"

@interface PhotoAnnotation() <MKAnnotation>

@end

@implementation PhotoAnnotation

- (id) initWithThumbnailUrl:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate url: (NSString*) thumbnailUrl{
    self = [super init];
    if(self){
        self.coordinate = coordinate;
        self.thumbnailUrl = thumbnailUrl;
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Assigned the MKAnnotation like this

```
 for(User* user in users){
                    self.photos = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
                    for(Photo* photo in user.photo){
                        CLLocationCoordinate2D location = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(photo.latitude, photo.longitude);
                        PhotoAnnotation* myAnnotation = [[PhotoAnnotation alloc]initWithThumbnailUrl: location url: photo.thumbnailUrl];
                        [self.photos insertObject:myAnnotation atIndex:0];
                    }
                }
```

This would successfully create the custom MKAnnotation on the map!